# How to Connect with Dbeaver on Snowflake (DUO Push)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I am using Duo Mobile for authentication  in snowflake .  I have entered username and password and warehouse details in Dbeaver. But I keep getting error

"DUO PUSH IS NOT ENABLED FOR YOUR MFA. PROVIDE A PASSCODE AS PART OF THE CONNECTION STRING" .

I have tried to see
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/error-duo-push-is-not-enabled-for-your-mfa-provide-a-passcode-as-part-of-the-connection-string

here it says to add "passcodeInPassword=on".

Where do I need to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we need to enable this parameter specifically for DUO to send the push notification. I tested this on DBeaver Community Version 21.2.2.202110030714 with a Snowflake user that is enabled for DUO and the connection (Test and Connect) works fine with the notification being received on the configured device.

Comment: Have you turned MFA on , in snowflake?

Comment: Yes, MFA is on and the Push Notification is seen for the user while logging in from UI and DBeaver.What is the version of JDBC connector being used in this set up? The JDBC string can be appended from DBeaver - Connection - Edit Driver Settings which is the last setting on the screen.

Comment: Manually Opened DUO Mobile and push notification was visible. whenI clcik on Accept . it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the Snowflake connection and hit 'Edit Connection' and then go to the 'Driver Properties' tab.  Then, add the 'passcode' as a 'User Property' and put the actual passcode in the 'Value' field.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver might be using the JDBC driver to create a connection to Snowflake.
You may need to pass it in the JDBC connection string at client (DBeaver) end.
See- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa.html#using-mfa-with-jdbc

Comment: where should I enter  JDBC connection string?